# Neato XV-11 LIDAR hector_slam mapping without odometry at walking speeds?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, xv-11, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was inspired by this video to get an XV-11 LIDAR for indoor mapping via hector_slam:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSlkjY-78SQ&feature=youtu.be

(Note that the walking speed is quite low--the video had to be sped up 2.5X.)

I'm finding in practice that the results shown at the end of the video may be "at best"--my maps are messy and jump around/overlap on themselves. This is probably due to a problem with the particular XV-11 unit I received (that will be returned/exchanged because it sometimes emits 0.0mm readings for entire revolutions), but while researching the map's jumpiness/overlapping, I'm finding that people either gave up on the XV-11 and went to a higher-end LIDAR with a higher scan rate or added odometry, both of which increase the project cost dramatically.

So, I am wondering, before I return/exchange this XV-11, has anyone gotten the XV-11 to do decent 2D mapping without odometry at walking speeds (1.5m/s)? Is it just not possible with a 5Hz (300rpm) LIDAR? I'm not asking for perfect maps, just usable ones (no walls where there aren't really walls, etc.)

I am basically tasked to do this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8pdObV_df4

(Note that the user is walking quite rapidly--probably faster than 1.5m/s. We'd love to be able to go this quickly.)

If you did get it working, how did you do it? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223390/neato-xv-11-lidar-hector_slam-mapping-without-odometry-at-walking-speeds?/) by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2016-01-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have access to a XV-11, but I'd be interested in looking at a bag file if you have one. I know of a few people who successfully used hector_slam with the XV-11, but I guess nobody used a very high walking speed of higher than 1.5 m/s with it so far.

At 1.5 m/s with 5 Hz, the robot travels 30cm between scans. A further complication is that scan acquisition is not discrete but continuous, so the scans are warped by the platform motion (see [high fidelity projection](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry#High_fidelity_projection)). At the slow scan rate and high movement speed this effect likely is much more pronounced than with other LIDARs and creates another chicken-and-egg problem (need to know platform motion to undistort scan, need undistorted scan for scanmatching and estimating platform motion).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) on 2016-01-03**:
Thanks for the reponse, Stefan! I do not have a bag file yet, since we suspect our XV-11 is faulty. We will probably not be getting a bag file at all, since we will likely upgrade to a Hokuyo UTM-30LX laser scanner based in a large part on your answers and past writings about your project.

**Comment by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) on 2016-01-03**:
May I ask one more question? Was the IMU required for the handheld UTM-30LX to do a scan without the map breaking, or could we reliably get unbroken maps without one? I am assuming that you were merely practicing for the IMU to be included in the ground robot.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-01-04**:
Depends on how much roll and pitch motion the sensor has and how the environment looks like. If you keep the sensor level and , a IMU is not required.

**Comment by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) on 2016-01-04**:
Thanks, Stefan! In our application, the floors will be very level and the only roll and pitch will be from the human tester's gait and hand motion. Later, when on a ground robot, the roll and pitch may be less than with the human tester. It sounds like an IMU is not necessary in either case.

**Comment by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) on 2016-01-04**:
BTW, Stefan--there are several people asking about how to integrate IMU data into hector_slam on the YouTube videos in the Team Hector channel. Perhaps if you have time, you could answer them... I too am curious about the code required. Thanks!